# My cell icon in table view change color

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios7, tableview

I'm transitioning my app to ios7, but i really don't understand some things. For example, the icon of this menu was in a white png, why in my app they are drawed gray?

[image: example of ios7 bad menu]

The images are picked by an array:

```
 menuItems = @[
        [NVMenuItem initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"HOME_LABEL", @"")
                    withImageName:@"recordMenuIcon.png"
                          itemType:NVHomeType requiresConnection:NO],
        [NVMenuItem initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LIBRARY_LABEL", @"")
                    withImageName:@"libraryMenuIcon.png"
                          itemType:NVLibraryType requiresConnection:YES],
```

and then in

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

there's the assignation

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:item.cellImage];
```

Comment: can you show the code where the image is set?

Comment: this is a third part library?

Comment: sorry, i'm failing. See the edited code.

Comment: Check the alpha on the imageView, and also check the selection mechanism.  It looks like you change the color of the text on selection-- perhaps it's not adjusting the alpha of the image.  Also, note that you should leave the ".png" off of image names when you call them like that.